# Multiprocessing Process os.system('kill -9 {0}'.format(pid)) fails on Linux

Tags: python, linux, process

when I use terminate in linux with python, I found the way to close the progress in the way os.system('kill -9 {0}'.format(pid)), but it failed.

My code is to run two progress.when the first progress finished, I want the second progress close too (the second progress it's self running all the time if you don't close it).

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)
progress1 = Process(target=main)
progress2 = Process(target=run_proxypool)
progress1.daemon = True
progress2.start()
pid = progress2.pid
time.sleep(10)
progress1.start()
progress1.join()
os.system('kill -9 {0}'.format(pid))
```

Comment: If you can provide the code, very grateful!

Comment: Have you considered using `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)` instead of spawning a subprocess for killing? Also, are you sure `progress2` is still running`? What happens when you switch it with a function that just sleeps forever?

Comment: @orip, I'm sure progress2 isstill running ,I now try to use `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)` to have a see!

Comment: Why not just do`progress2.terminate()` for instance?

Comment: @Torxed I first use the terminate(), it works on windows well. but on linux, it's failed!

Comment: @orip I change the code like this, but it doesn't work.
`progress1 = Process(target=main)`, `progress2 = Process(target=run_proxypool)`, `progress1.daemon = True`, `progress2.start()`, `pid = progress2.pid`, `time.sleep(10)`, `progress1.start()`, `progress1.join()`, `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)`.Is there anything wrong? I can't find the `signal.SIGKILL` in my python3.5

Comment: Probably because on Unix it will send `kill -15` nor not `kill -9`. Which is the correct way to go about things. `kill -9` will not gracefully shutdown, and I'm betting `run_proxypool` is a blocking call. And if you're not interested in shutting it down gracefully, just do `os.exit(1)` or the [https://www.g-loaded.eu/2016/11/24/how-to-terminate-running-python-threads-using-signals/] signal library to just shut everything down.

Comment: Try `os.kill(pid, 9)`. Also try printing `pid` and running `kill -9 pid` from the command line to see if it works. On Windows, you definitely want to `.terminate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're running on Linux. Also consider using `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)`.

Not exactly what you're asking, but consider switching to [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) for cross-platform goodness as well as conveniences such as [wait_procs](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.wait_procs) which will gracefully send SIGTERM, wait, then send SIGKILL.

`signal.SIGKILL` should be available on Linux (not on Windows).

The multiprocessing module [recently gained](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/2528) a `kill()` method that falls back to `terminate` on Windows.

Comment: Thanks! I'v sloved my question, I use `psutil` and `os.kill`. Finally I find the problem is my subprocess is not closed in my function. I think in the wrong way at first. thanks whatever.

Answer (score 0):

From https://clang.llvm.org/extra/doxygen/run-clang-tidy_8py_source.html:

```py
     # This is a sad hack. Unfortunately subprocess goes
     # bonkers with ctrl-c and we start forking merrily.
     print('\nCtrl-C detected, goodbye.')
     if tmpdir:
       shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
     os.kill(0, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the PID, here is how you can extract it and pass it to os.kill

```
import os, signal 
   
def process(name): 
    try: 
          
        # iterating through each instance of the proess 
        for line in os.popen("ps ax | grep " + name + " | grep -v grep"):  
            fields = line.split()               
            # extracting Process ID from the output 
            pid = fields[0]  
              
            # terminating process  
            #os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)  
        print("Process Successfully terminated") 
          
    except: 
        print("Error Encountered while running script") 
   
process()
```